# Draw on Loaded image on Android

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, imageview

i load the pic using this code

```
Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
filePathColumn, null, null, null);
cursor.moveToFirst();

int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
cursor.close();

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));`
```

it is work and shows the pic on imageview not I want draw a circle on it and save, I can draw it using this code

```
BitmapFactory.Options myOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
myOptions.inDither = true;
myOptions.inScaled = false;
myOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;// important
myOptions.inPurgeable = true;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_luncher);
Paint paint = new Paint();
paint.setAntiAlias(true);
paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

Bitmap workingBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap);
Bitmap mutableBitmap = workingBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);


Canvas canvas = new Canvas(mutableBitmap);
canvas.drawCircle(60, 50, 25, paint);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
imageView.setImageBitmap(mutableBitmap);`
```

But I cant draw because it set 'ic_luncher' on resource of bitmap.
so user can not draw on loaded pic, what code i should replace

`Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.ic_luncher);`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using Bitmap.copy, try just creating a new bitmap of the same size via createBitmap, then draw the launcher icon to this new bitmap.  Then you can draw on top of that.